# Pointers in a C program

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *ptr[10];
int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
*ptr[3]=a;
printf("%d",*ptr[3]);
return 0;
```

My question is about I want to print 3 in `a` array because `int *ptr[10]` means ten pointers, but it throws an error.

Comment: Why do you want to use an array of pointers (`int *ptr[10]`)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the overall goal of this code?

Comment: Line 3 (the assigment) is mixing an `int` with a pointer.  Line 4 (the `printf()` call) has problems with operator precedence — and you need another 3 in the expression.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but are you maybe trying to set up `ptr` to be an alias for `a`?  Of maybe for `*ptr` to be an alias for `a`?

Comment: _"it throws an error"_, could you share the verbatim error message with us?

Comment: **Always** include the full, *exact*, error message when asking about code that emits them. In this case the code. For example in this case ms cl v19 emits the error: *"error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'int [10]' to 'int'"*, which is all but self-explanatory. You're trying to assign the base of an integer array to `int`.

Comment: `ptr[3]` is uninitialized, so dereferencing it is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: You probably intended `ptr[3] = a` not `*ptr[3] = a`. `ptr[3]` is an `int *`. `ptr[3] = a` says you are assigning the pointer in the array `ptr` at index 3 to the address given by `a`. Your statement `*ptr[3] = a` is attempting to dereference (access the location given by) a pointer in `ptr[3]` that doesn't (yet) exist and so will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want put the start of the array `a` in position `3` of array of array `ptr`, you should remove the `*` in the line 3:

```
ptr[3] = a;
```

Also, the printing has some problem and you can write likes the following to be more clear:

```
printf("%d", ptr[3][0]); // will print the first value of array "a"
```

Comment: Probably `ptr[3][3]` to print the 3 from array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you say you are trying to print "3" via

> ```
> printf("%d",*ptr[3]);
> ```

and on the definition of array `a`, I think you're trying to set up `*ptr` to be an alias for `a`.

In that case, however, you have an operator precedence problem: the indexing operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereferencing operator (`*`), so `*ptr[3]` means "the object pointed to by element 3 of `ptr`", whereas what you want is actually "element 3 of the array pointed to by `ptr`."  Re-read those until you recognize and understand the important difference between them.

But the problem is not limited to that expression; related precedence problems extend throughout:

- a pointer to an array of ten `int`s would be declared like so:

  ```
  int (*ptr)[10];
  ```
- with that declaration, you would assign `ptr` to point to `a` via a simple:

  ```
  ptr = &a;
  ```
- having done that, you would print element 3 of the pointed-to array like so:

  ```
  printf("%d", (*ptr)[3]);
  ```

---

**Alternatively**, perhaps you mean to make `ptr` itself (not `*ptr`) an alias of `a`.  In that case, you want a pointer to a single `int`, not a pointer to an array, and certainly not an array of pointers:

```
int *ptr;
```

You could then assign the pointer value simply via

```
ptr = a;
```

. Having established `ptr` as an alias for `a`, you could then use it as such in your `printf` call:

```
printf("%d", ptr[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an array of pointers to point to an array.  One pointer is fine.  All of these print '3'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *ptr;
    int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    ptr = &a[3];            /* point to specific element */
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    ptr = a;                /* point to whole array */
    printf("%d\n", ptr[3]);
    printf("%d\n", 3[ptr]); /* pointer arithmetic is weird */
    return(0);
}
```